# Execute a react webpack bundle without a server

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a simple `React` application that was built up with various `node_modules`.  The application runs fine when I bundle the application into `index.html` and `app.js` and serve it from a `webpack-dev-server` instance.  I tried to also point straight to the `index.html` file in chrome, expecting it to run the application as normal, given it has access to the bundled `app.js` though nothing loads.

My question is, what does the `webpack-dev-server` provide that I dont have when hitting the `index.html` file directly?  I would have thought that everything that is needed by the application is included in the `app.js` bundle?

I don't have any static assets to worry about at the minute, this is a pretty simple react application that should render some basic components, that will display some text / buttons.

Console is empty and the network tab looks like the following -

[image]

Comment: What does the network and console panels in Chrome say? Do you get any loading messages?

Comment: You can build static files which you can host on any webserver, but depending on how you bundle CSS and images + how you've linked to the main JS file you may have different problems

Comment: @Peter , ive added some more detail to the question

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but I think you just didn't generate your bundle.

Webpack-server builds your files with webpack and keeps `app.js` in the memory. When you stop webpack-dev-server, there is no `app.js` file which your `index.html` could pick up. You simply need to use your webpack configuration to to build your `app.js` file.

add script to your package.json like:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config directory/webpack.config.js --progress"
},
```

and then run `nam run build`, it should then generate your app bundle which then paste to directory of your `index.html` so it can pick it up.

Comment: I'm doing the build step and it Is building an app.js though that's making me think that when I think it's working via the webpack-dev-server that it's the in memory bundle that I'm seeing working and not the bundle that is built during the build process.

Comment: Thats correct. Clearly you html cannot find `app.js` otherwise you would get JS errors in console. It would help If you could show your files structure and index.html. Try to clear you your browser cache as well.